# Setting a class in the stylesheet instead of the markup

Tags: css

I'm trying to apply my poor knowledge of CSS to a little toy project I have going, and it's annoying me endlessly that I have to declare column widths in my HTML markup.

Is there a way so that I can, instead of

```
<div class="grid_4"></div>
```

use something like

```
<div id="leftNav"></div>
```

and in the stylesheet apply the grid_4 class to the element with id leftNav?

In my mind it would look something like this

```
#leftNav {
    apply-class: grid_4;
}
```

Is there anything like that available in CSS?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? CSS won't let you do it, but you can get Javascript to dynamically assign classes. But if you explain more about the background, we can probably come up with a more natural approach.

Comment: I don't like sticking layout in my markup, really.

Comment: Well, if you call your class `leftNav`, that's basically sticking layout into your markup as well... ;-P I agree though.

Comment: You are not sticking anything in your markup by assigning a class. All that it does is to allow CSS and Javascript to target the element. You seem to want to apply the same kind of treatment to a number of elements (otherwise you could just use the element ID) that cannot otherwise be grouped (such as selected by shared parent), so why not give them a common class?

Comment: If you don't like sticking layout in your markup, don't use a grid framework, especially if you only have rudimentary knowledge of CSS.

Comment: deceze: Score!
BoltClock's a Unicorn: but they're so prettifying!
Thilo: Because the classes in grid frameworks aren't for styling, but for layout. Radically different elements will still use the same classes.

Anyway, seems Sass is the way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in regular CSS, no.

There are CSS preprocessors though, which create a new mini-language which then gets processed into regular CSS, which add those and more features. See [less](http://lesscss.org/), [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/).

Comment: This looks promising. In SASS, I take it would be possible to do something like #nav { @extend .grid_4 } ?

Comment: You'd probably be looking at *mixins* instead, but yeah, either one will probably do it.